# To use or not use a stepper

Tags: mobile-application, e-commerce, ux-designer, counter

I'm designing an app where users can go to buy artworks. The catch is a user can only "purchase one artwork at a time". Is including an inactive stepper showing 1 count good for user experience? I also have the thought of including a micro-copy but have no idea what it should say.

Answer (score 1):

Is there ever a situation where this stepper is active? If not, then this is not the appropriate control. Why is the inactive stepper shown at all?

If a lot of other things can be bought and only the artwork has this restriction, then the inactive stepper could work (though I am pretty sure users will be confused why the cannot change the number for just that item).